# How to print div contains canvas to PDF file?

Tags: javascript, css, html, pdf, canvas

I have a div with many the canvas (with same the canvas as a page PDF). I want to print div, which contain all canvas to PDF file. It is important to know how to print numbers of canvas as PDF pages (sample 4 canvas have to 4 pages PDF) and page PDF follow portrait orientation or landscape orientation (sample file PDF landscape orientation if canvas horizontal).

```
<div id="pdf_view">
<canvas class="pdf_canvas">
<canvas class="pdf_canvas">
<canvas class="pdf_canvas">
<canvas class="pdf_canvas">
</div>
<button id="print"></button>
$('#print').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       ////do something 
});
```

I try some 3-partys `canvas2pdf` , `jspdf`, `html2canvas` but seems they are not exactly what I want. Have you idea for this , give me a direction. thank all.